# Когда перегрузка операторов это плохо?

Tags: c++, перегрузка-операторов, операторы

Перегрузка операторов крайне удобная возможность языка С++. Ведь можем написать:

```
#include <iostream>
class Point2i
{
  int x;
  int y;

  public:
    Point2i(int x, int y):x(x),y(y){}

    bool operator==(const Point2i &  other)
    {
        return x == other.x && y == other.y ? true:false;
    }
};

int main() {
   Point2i p1(12, 3);
   Point2i p2(1, -11);

   if(p1 == p2)
      std::cout<<"p1==p2"<<'\n';

   return 0;
}
```

Скорее всего бывают случаи когда это не уместно.

Когда перегрузка операторов это плохо?

P.S Имеется в виду о любых операторах

Comment: `bool operator==(const Point2i &other) const`. А лучше: `friend bool operator==(const Point2i &lhs, const Point2i &rhs)`. А уж `... ? true : false` - это еще одна странная и необъяснимая манера написания кода.

Comment: Есть мнение, что собственно наличие в языке операторов - очень сомнительная фича.

Comment: @VTT, почему???

Comment: Потому что наличие в языке операторов не позволяет делать чего-то такого, что было бы нельзя сделать без них. Проще говоря, они не добавляют ничего нового. Однако при этом усложняют синтаксис языка и делают его еще менее консистентным. Также некоторым не очень нравится, что операторы, позаимствованные из математики, имеют другой смысл, а что перегруженные операторы часто отличаются по смыслу от неперегруженных.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

В качестве эпиграфа:

> — Нужно потреблять, но не злоупотреблять, — поучительным тоном заметил Арамис.
>   А. Дюма, *"Три мушкетера"*

Это очень плохо, когда нарушается семантика (попросту, смысл) оператора.

Например, возьмем ваши точки. Что такое их вычитание или умножение? (если это точки, а не двумерные вектора). Или что такое отношение `<` для точек? хотя никто не мешает вам написать, например, сравнение модулей расстояний от начала координат. Или еще чего - но это будет *неочевидное* сравнение. А ведь можно написать оператор `<`, который будет, скажем, выводить суммы всех четырех координат :)

Или, например, то же отношение равенства, как вы написали, но которое возвращает не `bool`, а считает, скажем, какую-то строку - пусть те же `"true"` и `"false"`.

Такое применение запутывает всех читающих код, в том числе самого автора.

Есть еще хитрые случаи, связанные с поиском имен, но это уже достаточно большая редкость.

А главное - смотри эпиграф. Ничто не следует использовать только по той причине, что его можно использовать. Вы никогда не видели "картин", которые создают малолетки, научившиеся какой-то возможности в фотошопе, и использующие ее только потому, что "вот как я умею!" (кстати, грешат этим и взрослые, особенно в кино...)? Или тексты, изобилующие одновременно 20 шрифтами? :) Вот просто не делайте такие программы, и все будет хорошо :)

P.S. Кстати, не забывайте, что ассоциативность и приоритеты операторов сохраняются, так что сделать, скажем, оператор `^` оператором возведения в степень оказывается, гм... не очень умной идеей.

Comment: Печально, что сама стандартная библиотека этим страдает. Например, что такое побитовый сдвиг для байтового потока? `cout<<2`

Comment: @ГерманБорисов *"Есть такое правило - нет правил без исключений"* (с) :)

Answer (score 3):

Конкретный пример языковой неконсистентности, потенциально приводящий к эпическим фейлам. В С++ для встроенных логических операторов вычисление правого операнда не производится, если после вычисления значения левого операнда результат операции определен. Например в `Is_Good() && Do_Work()` функция `Do_Work` не будет вызвана, если `Is_Good` возвращает `false`. Однако для перегруженных логических операторов это не соблюдается! Кроме того, операнды перегруженного логического оператора могут вычисляться вообще в любом порядке, так что в этом примере при использовании `tribool` функция `Do_Work` внезапно вызывается даже до `Is_Good`:

```
#include <boost/logic/tribool.hpp>
#include <boost/logic/tribool_io.hpp>
#include <iostream>

template<typename x_Bool> class t_Fancy
{
    private: x_Bool Is_Good(void) const
    {
        ::std::cout << "is not good!" << ::std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    // must be called only when Is_Good returns true!
    private: x_Bool Do_Work(void) const
    {
        ::std::cout << "FAIL" << ::std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    public: x_Bool Work(void) const
    {
        return Is_Good() && Do_Work();
    }
};

int main()
{
    ::std::cout << ::std::boolalpha << t_Fancy<bool>{}.Work() << ::std::endl;
    ::std::cout << ::std::boolalpha << t_Fancy<::boost::tribool>{}.Work() << ::std::endl;
    return 0;    
}
```

[online compiler](https://wandbox.org/permlink/KoHIDt2IxRDMXlrx)

> is not good!
>   false
>   FAIL
>   is not good!
>   false