# Набор условий в if C++

Tags: c++, if

К примеру есть такой код

```
if (условие1 || условие2 || условие3 || условие4) {
    cout << "Enter again";
    }
```

Если условие1 будет true то оператор выполнится сразу или пройдет проверка дальше по условие2,3 и так далее? 
Или если условие 2 будет true.
У меня если условие1 true, то в условие2 может быть деление на 0.
(Я понимаю что || это или)

Comment: см https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/949440/Когда-перегрузка-операторов-это-плохо/949551#949551

Comment: Правильно понимаете. Первое же true в таких условиях `по или` (также как и первое false в условиях `по и`) прекращает вычисления и происходит переход к операторам внутри блока

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Условия проверяются слева направо, и если какое-то из них окажется `true`, следующие НЕ вычисляются.

`&&` работает аналогично, но останавливается при `false` условии (по понятным причинам).

---

Однако если оператор был перегружен, то этот механизм перестает работать - оба операнда вычисляются всегда.

Comment: В С++17 порядок (sequencing) вычисления операндов *перегруженного* оператора берется от оригинального *встроенного* оператора. Именно это теперь гарантирует предсказуемый порядок вычисления перегруженного оператора вывода `<<`. И для перегруженного `&&`: да, оба операнда вычисляются, но порядок вычисления слева-направо должен гарантироваться. См.напр. https://stackoverflow.com/a/41227595/187690

Comment: @AnT Почитал cpprefrence, действительно все так. Спасибо, поправил.